# (Warning) Ubuntu-Server overlaps and earlier Alias

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-server

There's a warn after i type sudo service apache2 restart.

```
 * Restarting web server apache2
[Thu Sep 26 05:46:24 2013] [warn] The Alias directive in /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf at line 3 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.
... waiting
[Thu Sep 26 05:46:25 2013] [warn] The Alias directive in /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf at line 3 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.
```

it shows after i start the apache2.

[image: Warn]

Already tried this solution but didn't work for me. Anyone can help?

Comment: Which solution did you try?

Comment: http://tech.enekochan.com/2013/05/08/solve-the-alias-directive-in-will-probably-never-match-because-ir-overlaps-an-earlier-alias/ this but didn't work

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I've found that the contents of `apache.conf` are already being loaded by `phpmyadmin.conf` located in `/etc/apache2/conf.d` which means that you can **remove** (or comment) the following line from your `apache2.conf` file.

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: location of the file: /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Answer (score 2):

It appears as if you may have manually edited or copied the configuration file in order to create an Alias statement for the phpMyAdmin file, but the package manager also did that for you, so you seem to now have two statements that overlap.

Comment: Then how to fix that? it still show after restarting the apache2 service

Comment: In that case, simply undo the changes you manually made.